# How to solve linearly constrained quadratic program with many variables?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization, python, quadratic-programming

Suppose I have the following quadratic program

$$\begin{array}{ll} \underset{v_1, v_2, \dots, v_m \in \mathbb{R}^n}{\text{minimize}} & \displaystyle\sum_i v_i^T a_i + \displaystyle\sum_{i,j} \lambda_{i,j} \, v_i^T A v_j\\ \text{subject to} & \displaystyle\sum_i v_i^T b_{k,i} = c_k, \quad \forall k\\ & v_1, v_2, \dots, v_m \geq \vec{0}\end{array}$$

where $a_i, b_{k,i} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\lambda_{i,j}, c_k \in \mathbb{R}$, and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$.

How to solve a quadratic program like this? Is there any way to re-write in canonical QP form? If not, is there any Python package that can solve quadratic program like this?

(edit) Is $\sum_{i,j}\lambda_{i,j} \: v_i^TAv_j$ just

$$\begin{bmatrix} v_1^T &v_2^T & \dotsb & v_m^T\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} \lambda_{1,1}A&\lambda_{1,2}A& \dotsb & \lambda_{1,m}A\\\lambda_{2,1}A&\lambda_{2,2}A& \dotsb & \lambda_{2,m}A\\ \vdots&\vdots& \ddots & \lambda_{m-1,m}A \\\lambda_{m,1}A&\lambda_{m,2}A & \dotsb  &\lambda_{m,m}A\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} v_1^T \\v_2^T \\ \vdots \\ v_m^T\end{bmatrix}
$$

So it's equivalent to the one variable situation?

Comment: Try to rewrite in matrix form.  Note that you should not expect non-convex QPs to be easy. If non-convex QPs were always easy, many hard combinatorial problems would also be easy.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo where could one read further about your later statement?

Comment: Yes. ILP is NP-hard, as it can solve e.g. Maximum clique. Furthermore, concave LP with all variables constrained to $0\le x\le 1$ is equivalent to the ILP with $x\in\{0,1\}$, and for variables $x\in \{0,1\}$ quadratic monomials and linear monomials behave equal, so you get in the end that also quadratic programming is NP hard. Not really a gentle introduction, but the following article proofs all the links: https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007%2F978-0-387-74759-0_536

Comment: You may want to try out cplex and gurobi. They can solve non-convex QPs. They also often find good solutions fairly quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Let's set

$$
\begin{align}
\bf{v} &= (v_1, \ldots, v_m) = (v_{11}, \ldots, v_{1n}, \ldots, v_{m1}, \ldots, v_{mn}) \in \mathbb{R}^{n \cdot m} \\
%
\bf{a} &= (a_1, \ldots, a_m) = (a_{11}, \ldots, a_{1n}, \ldots, a_{m1}, \ldots, a_{mn}) \in \mathbb{R}^{n \cdot m} \\
%
\bf{B} &= \begin{pmatrix} %
b_{111} & \ldots & b_{11n} & \ldots & b_{1m1} & \ldots & b_{1mn} \\ 
\vdots & & & & & & \vdots \\
b_{p11} & \ldots & b_{p1n} & \ldots & b_{pm1} & \ldots & b_{pmn}\\ 
\end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times m\cdot n} \\
%
c &= (c_1, \ldots, c_p) \in \mathbb{R}^{p} \\
\Lambda &= (\lambda_{i,j})_{i = 1, \ldots, n, j = 1, \ldots, n} \\
{\bf D} &= \text{diag}{(\Lambda \cdot A, \ldots, \Lambda \cdot A}) \in \mathbb{R}^{m \cdot n \times m \cdot n}
\end{align}
$$

Then, we have

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{m} v_i^{\top} b_{k,i} &= c_k \quad \forall k = 1,\ldots, p \iff {\bf B v} = c.  \\ %
\sum_{i=1}^{m} v_i^{\top} a_i &= \bf{a}^{\top} v \\
\sum_{i=1}^{m} \sum_{i=1}^{m} \lambda_{i,j} v_i^{\top} A v_j &= {\bf{v^{\top}}} {\bf D} {\bf v} \\
\end{align}
$$

and consequently

$$
\begin{align}
&\min_{{\bf v}} &\quad {\bf{v^{\top}}} {\bf D} {\bf v} + {\bf{a}}^{\top} {\bf v} \\
&\text{s.t.} &\quad {\bf B v} &= c \\
&& {\bf v} &\geq 0  
\end{align}
$$

However, as already mentioned in the comments, non-convex QPs are quite hard to solve towards global optimality. Therefore, one usually settles for a local minimizer. Here, you can use the Ipopt solver ([cyipopt](https://github.com/mechmotum/cyipopt) is a python interface for the Ipopt solver). In case you really need a global minimum, you can use the commercial solver Gurobi. They offer free academic licenses.